# How can we identify status of switch button in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Hi,                                                                                          I need to identify status of switch button when I enter into my web page. Depending upon status I have to perform my action using selenium webdriver .                                                                                          Need to know if it is ON or OFF. I have a class name to identify the object. Please let me know.                                                                                         Thanks,

Comment: Show the code please, both HTML and Selenium code.

Answer (score 0):

To give a more useful answer I would need to see the HTML for the element but you could try and adapt something like this:

```
boolean isChecked = "true".equals(driver.waitFor(By.id(id)).getAttribute("checked"));
```

My elements have a 'checked' attribute that is set to true when they are checked. This will tell me if the checkbox is checked (true) or it isn't (false). I can then do:

```
if(isChecked){
    //do what you need to do when box is checked
}else{
    //do what you need to do when box is not checked
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you scott.                                                   <div class="class1" id="id1" ui="appView-swIcFirst" checked="true" value="On"></div>
<div class="classDefault"></div>
<div class="class2texton"><span>On</span></div>
<div class="class3textoff"><span>Off</span></div>
above is how html looks. please resolve and help me :)

Comment: Then simply swap the id in my example above for "id1" and that should give you the result you need.

Comment: Or you can modify it to search for class as shown by Sunita below.

Comment: @Raghav If you have extra information, it's best to edit your question to included it there. It makes it much more readable; and also, any new readers will be able to get all the information they need from just the question, without having to scan through all the comments and responses.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott mentioned, without html it is difficult but here is how you can find the element by its class

```
if driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('.<class_name>:checked)){...}
```